# JQuery creating wrong URL in $.ajax method

Tags: jquery

I am wondering if there are any utility methods (perhaps similar to c# `Path.Combine`) to create URLs in jquery. I have a webapp. If I access it by typing `http://mymachine/myapp/` in my web browser and then make [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) request with `url='search'`, the request is made to `http://mymachine/myapp/search`. So far so good.

However, if I access my webapp by typing `http://mymachine/myapp` in my web browser, the app will load, but then if I make an $.ajax call with same url, jquery emits a request to `http://mymachine/search` - this is not what I want. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What server side language is your app written in?

Comment: what is `myapp` is it the application name

Comment: because you are using relative paths, it is always better use application contextpath and make a absolute url reference instead of a relative url

Comment: myapp is application name. I am using c# as server side language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your server side language to set the application base url in js:

ex:

```
<script>

    var baseUrl = '<%=Server.ApplicationPath%>';

</script>
```

Comment: I think this is correct answer. Use @Request.ApplicationPath in asp.net mvc

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to calculate the base URL while making the Ajax request.

The URL you should provide is -

```
url = '/myapp/search'


Hence the request will goto - http://myhostname/myapp/search
```

For more information refer -

[Relative URLs in AJAX requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765740/relative-urls-in-ajax-requests)

Comment: this is not good as the name of the application (myapp in this case) is hardcoded in javascript.