# Incorrect Ajax target when request sent from different URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the same ajax request firing from two locations:

```
$.post("/conversations", ... );
```

Fired from `domain.com/chat`, the request is sent to `domain.com/conversations` correctly.

Fired from `domain.com/u/blah`, the request is sent to `domain.com/u/conversations` incorrectly.

How do I get both to send to the former's destination?

Comment: Help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765740/relative-urls-in-ajax-requests . Had to change to `$.post("/conversations/", ... );`

Comment: If the location is always the same use: `"//"+location.host+"/conversations"`