# Why is the MVC controller action method tagged as HttpPost not getting invoked from external javascript file?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

Here is the relevant View cshtml code

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var task in Model.TasksSummaryList)
    {
        <tr>
            <th onclick="OnPatientSelected('@task.PatientID')">@task.PatientName</th>
            <th>@task.Status</th>
            <th>@task.TaskCount</th>
            <th>@task.MostRecentTask</th>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Here is the external javascript file containing OnPatientSelected

```
function OnPatientSelected(selectedPatientID) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "TasksSummary/TaksSummaryDetailsView",
        data: { selectedPatientID: selectedPatientID },
        error: function () {
            alert("fail");
        },
        success: function(){
        alert("success");
        }
    });
    }
```

This always shows success but never calls the Controller ActionMethod I want

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult TasksSummaryDetailsView(/*data from view*/string selectedPatientID)
        {
            int i = 09;
            //Received PatientID from View (Client)
            //Browse to the appropriate view 
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: can you keep a breakpoint in your action method and check if its being hit

Comment: How have you verified that the action isn't being invoked? Also, note that the `url` provided is [relative to the current page's address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765740/relative-urls-in-ajax-requests) and may not result in the path you expect.

Comment: Try using fiddler to see what calls are being made and whats the output. Also, try the url directly in browser to see if it works : `.../TasksSummary/TaksSummaryDetailsView?selectedPatientID="yourvalue"`

Comment: So the only way it works in browser is if I remove the [HttPost] tag on top of method name but when I place it, I get an error saying ActionName does not exist.......
A public action method 'TasksSummaryDetailsView' was not found on controller 'eRxWeb.Areas.CodeAThonMVC.Controllers.TasksSummaryController'.

Answer (score 1):

The path needs to be relative, try something like the following:

```
url: "../TasksSummary/TaksSummaryDetailsView",
```

Or even better:

```
url: '@Url.Action("TasksSummary", "TasksSummaryDetailsView")',
```

Comment: So I tried all possible combinations. Still not working.
My controller file is TasksSummaryController.cs and that contains HttpPost tagged action method TasksSummaryDetaillsView

Answer (score -1):

So replaced the url line in ajax call with the following and it works

url: 'TasksSummaryDetailsView'

Comment: You didn't explain why this works.  Do you understand why this fixed the problem?  Or did you just repeat what James P already said in his answer?

Comment: So since the paths were relative, using the above line worked. No F12 network errors.