# Spring boot not redirecting to desired page

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot

below is my Controller class.

```
@Controller
public class BankController {

@Autowired
private CustomerService customerService;
@Autowired
private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

@RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String actionLogin(@RequestParam String email, @RequestParam String password, Model model){
    List<Customer> byEmail = customerRepository.findByEmail(email);
    Customer customer = byEmail.get(0);
    if(BCrypt.checkpw(password, customer.getHashedPassword())){
        model.addAttribute("customer", customer);
        return "enterSiteView.html";
    }


    return "errorView.html";
}
```

I have kept `enterSiteView.html, errorView.html` in templates folder as given in the documentation.
When I click the login button the url does change to `http://localhost:9090/enterSiteView.html` but it displays an error as.

```
Whitelabel Error Page 
application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a     fallback.

Sun Oct 23 14:03:43 IST 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available`
```

My `enterSiteView.html` has nothing but just a Hello World text.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello Earth</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Login Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Sign-Up/Login Form</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,300,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="form">

<ul class="tab-group">
    <li class="tab active"><a href="#signup">Sign Up</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="#login">Log In</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="signup">
        <h1>Sign Up for Free</h1>

        <form action="/register" method="post">

            <div class="top-row">
                <div class="field-wrap">
                    <label>
                        First Name<span class="req">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" required autocomplete="off"/>
                </div>

                <div class="field-wrap">
                    <label>
                        Last Name<span class="req">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" required autocomplete="off"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="field-wrap">
                <label>
                    Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
                </label>
                <input type="email" required autocomplete="on"/>
            </div>

            <div class="field-wrap">
                <label>
                    Set A Password<span class="req">*</span>
                </label>
                <input type="password" required autocomplete="off"/>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="button button-block"/>Get Started</button>

        </form>

    </div>

    <div id="login">
        <h1>Welcome Back!</h1>

        <form action="/login" method="post">

            <div class="field-wrap">
                <label>
                    Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
                </label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required autocomplete="off"/>
            </div>

            <div class="field-wrap">
                <label>
                    Password<span class="req">*</span>
                </label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required autocomplete="off"/>
            </div>

            <p class="forgot"><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></p>

            <button class="button button-block"/>
            Log In</button>

        </form>

    </div>

</div><!-- tab-content -->

</div> <!-- /form -->
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have places index.html in static for the welcomepage. After the login is successful it should redirect to the desired page, instead it shows the above error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have common path [scheme](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23095_01/Platform.93/ATGProgGuide/html/s0803httpservletrequest01.html) of java web application:

```
[host]:[port]/MyWebApplication/personal/info/top.html
```

where:

- MyWebApplication is [context path](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath()) (in microservices application mapped
  to root by default)
- personal - is a [servlet path](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getServletPath())
- info/top.html is a [path info](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPathInfo())

  requestURI = contextPath + servletPath + pathInfo

So you redirecting base on relative path, it means that if you: specify this way :

```
return "redirect: errorView.html"
```

it directs you

```
(requestURI - last path part) + errorView.html
```

if you came from `http://example.com/user/path/to/info.html` , you redirect to  `http://example.com/user/path/to/errorView`, but if you came from `http://example.com/user` , you redirect to `http://example.com/errorView.html`. So changes only last request path part.

When you use :

```
return "redirect: /errorView.html"
```

it directs you

```
context path  + new servlet path(/errorView.html)
```

if you came from `http://example.com/user/path/to/info` , you redirect to `http://example.com/errorView.html`. Doesn't matter how long request path is.

Upd: if you take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765740/relative-urls-in-ajax-requests/4765962#4765962) excellent post, you never face problem with relative path again