# Passing data from View to Controller using Ajax results in 404 error on the controller method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to pass data from View to Controller Action method. Using Ajax to pass the data to the controller but the controller doesn't receive the data and it is always null resulting in 404 error.
Can someone review this and point out what needs to be fixed?

Ajax call in View -

```
  function openErrorDetails(errors) {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/Home/ErrorDetails",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ errors }),
            success: function (data) {
                var win = window.open();
                win.document.write(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

Calling the Ajax funtion using a anchor tag OnClick event to open a new window with the errors details -

var exception = "onClick='openErrorDetails(" + JSON.stringify(data) + ")'> View details";

Controller -

```
    [HttpPost]

    public ActionResult ErrorDetails(string errors)
    {

        if (errors != null)
        {
            dynamic errorMessages = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(errors);

            return View("ErrorDetails", errorMessages);
        }
        else
        {
            return new HttpNotFoundResult();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the whole controller file?

Comment: I wonder what the controller has at the top of the file.  i.e. routing info

Comment: no routing info. It does execute the controller method but errors is null.

Comment: Change your relative url to an absolute one and see if that helps.  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765740/relative-urls-in-ajax-requests

Comment: Have you tried without stringify?

Comment: yes, doesn't work. still returns null to the controller method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this solved it
data: { errors: JSON.stringify({ errors }) },