# Can't using ajax call api in dotnet core 3.1?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, ajax

my class api:

```
[Route("Api")]
[ApiController]
public class ApiUsersController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Users/demo")]
    public ActionResult demo([FromBody]model data)
    {
       return  "OK";
    }
}
```

my script jquery:

```
var model = {key: "123"}
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'Api/Users/demo',
    data: JSON.stringify(model),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    async: true,
    ...
});
```

I can't call api in project, please help me

how to resold problem

Comment: Hi @kai, what is your model design? Does it contains string type property and the property named key? Also, what's the error message you get? F12 in the browser and check the console panel if any error. And check the output panel in visual studio if any error. Pls share with us.

Comment: this api url not found error, when i change  url 'Api/Users/demo' to http://localhost:1234/Api/Users/demo ajax works fine

Comment: Hi @kai, so the issue resolved now, right?

Comment: no, i want my url to be 'Api/Users/demo' when call ajax

Comment: Hi @kai, just for confirmation, do you use two project here? I mean does the script and the api exists in different project?

Comment: Try `/Api/Users/demo` (with prepended `/`)

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4765962/1025555

Comment: yes, i using web mvc dot net core + web api in a project

Comment: i try but not work

Comment: Please show the HTTP request that's being issued by your code. You can see it when you open your browser's dev tools (networking tab).

Comment: Hi @kai, if you use the different project, of course you need specify the port number... otherwise it will append your current project port number and cannot find this api..

Answer (score 0):

Change
public ActionResult demo(model data)
To
public ActionResult demo( **[FromBody]** model data)

Works in my case:
[image]

[image]

Comment: i'm sorry for the lack of fact i added it but still not working

Comment: what is the response codein browser?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Change your **contentType** and try:

```
var model = {key: "123"}
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'Api/Users/demo',
    data: model,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    //async: true,
    ...
});
```